# How do I increase the font size on Evernote?

Tags: evernote

Is there a way to increase the font size on Evernote?

So far I've only been able to use the default size and changing the paragraph style (but it works only for a line).

Comment: Are you using web client or another application?

Answer (score 2):

If you go in the the Evernote webapp, then select the note that you want to change the font.

Whenever you click the edit button, at the top of the actual note textbox, you will get toolbar with the usual bold-italic-underline-etc button + some others function.  In there, you can select the font and size.

You only have to select the text to change and select the style of the text.

Comment: So, there is no way to change it from iPad, or at least to set the default fonts for all notes ? Should I change the font size one by one from the web app ?

Comment: In the iOS release, it is very ney that you can do anything more than plain text ... so probably they are working on letting us change the font ... but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found is to copy the text, paste it into a new app (say Word), then paste it back into Evernote. It takes time, but it seems to work (I *just* discovered this and haven't given it a full trial) and will do for me until the Evernote developers come up with a *real* fix.